# Dotnet core rider snap ubuntu msbuild

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, rider

I want to migrate a small project from mono to core on Ubuntu. The problem is I cannot create a Core project using Rider.

I used snap to install Rider and coresdk.

Rider detects core. But when I go to create a new project it either hangs or I get

MSBuild error details:
Protocol Connection already terminated.

Has anyone encountered this. I don't really want to use the Microsoft msbuild.

Comment: New projects can always be created at terminal using `dotnet new`.

Comment: Probably because you use .net SDK 6.X. Try Rider 2021.2 builds (EAP program)

Answer (score 0):

Installing using `apt` fixed the problem.